# How to Create a Purchase Receipt with Document Details via code

Tags: acumatica

The Goal is creating a Purchase Order and then its corresponding Purchase Order receipt via code with 2 separate actions/buttons.

The PO (Type Normal) is created without any issues. And is then Approved via code making it visible in the "Add Purchase Order" smartpanel from the Purchase Receipt page.

[image]

The UI workflow would be the selection of the PO order and then pressing on "ADD PO".

I'm looking to replicate that via code.

Looking at the page's ASPX definition I can see that the smartpanel button is associated to action **AddPOOrder2**

I'm creating the Purchase receipt like this:

```
 if (orderRecord.Approved == true)
{
    poReceiptEntryGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POReceiptEntry>();

    receiptRow = new POReceipt();

    //Summary
    receiptRow.ReceiptType = "RT";
    receiptRow = poReceiptEntryGraph.Document.Insert(receiptRow);

    receiptRow.Hold = false;
    receiptRow.ReceiptDate = DateTime.Now;
    receiptRow.VendorID = orderRecord.VendorID;
    receiptRow.InvoiceNbr = "123";
    poReceiptEntryGraph.Document.Update(receiptRow);

    poReceiptEntryGraph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Then I create a PXView:

```
int startActualRow = PXView.StartRow;
int totalActualRows = 1;

List<Object> createdView = new PXView(poReceiptEntryGraph, false, PXSelect<POOrder, Where<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>
    .GetCommand()).Select(PXView.Currents, /*Filter value from the BQL Required*/ new object[] { "PO000683"/*orderRecord.OrderNbr*/ },
    PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters,
    ref startActualRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalActualRows);

PXView dummyActualView = new DummyView(poReceiptEntryGraph, poReceiptEntryGraph.Document.View.BqlSelect, createdView);
```

Finally, the PXView is used to press on the AddPOOrder2 action:

```
poReceiptEntryGraph.addPOOrder2.Press(new PXAdapter(dummyActualView));
poReceiptEntryGraph.Actions.PressSave();
```

No error messages are received and the summary section of the Receipt gets created correctly but without any content in the grid.

I also attempted to use **addPOOrder** which is another Acumatica action that executes addPOOrder2 but the result was the same.

Any ideas if I'm missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

Acumatica's AddPOOrder2 action iterates over the selected records and invokes method **AddPurchaseOrder**

Invoking the method directly in my action worked correctly:

```
if (orderRecord.Approved == true)

{
    poReceiptEntryGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POReceiptEntry>();
    receiptRow = new POReceipt();

    receiptRow.ReceiptType = "RT";
    receiptRow = poReceiptEntryGraph.Document.Insert(receiptRow);

    receiptRow.Hold = false;
    receiptRow.ReceiptDate = DateTime.Now;
    receiptRow.VendorID = orderRecord.VendorID;
    poReceiptEntryGraph.Document.Update(receiptRow);

    poReceiptEntryGraph.Actions.PressSave();

    poReceiptEntryGraph.AddPurchaseOrder(orderRecord);

    poReceiptEntryGraph.Actions.PressSave();
    }
```

However, I wonder, had the method not existed, was I in the correct path with the use of the PXView and the PXAdapter? Is it possible to execute other similar actions that may not have a method?